# IA32 Jump Table

Tags: assembly, x86

Im doing some homework and confused re: this line of code:

```
ja  8048448 <switch_prob+0x28>
```

I understand everything except for the  part ... how is that modifying the jump to 8048448? (I believe this is the break statement)

Let me know if more code is needed.

Thanks

Comment: `how is that modifying the jump` - what do you mean? The `ja` means `jump if above`. That is, the jump is taken based on whether certain flags are set (one value was above another value), usually because of a `cmp` or an arithmetic instruction.

Comment: what does the <switch_prob+0x28> do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<switch_prob+0x28>` is just a label + offset the disassembler uses to make the address `8048448` look more meaningful to humans.

Answer (score 1):

@echristopherson already correctly answered your question: What you have there is conditional jump (`ja` stands for *jump if above*) to 8048448. As he also mentions `<switch_prob+0x28>` is just a label generated by the debugger or disassembler to be used to refer to 8048448. This is only to improve the readability, nothing more.

My contribution here is to explain that this doesn't have anything to do with jump tables mentioned in the title (*IA32 Jump Table*). With a jump table you'd store target addresses in memory and perform an indirect jump based on the said jump table. As an example you might have:

```
mov eax,0
jump [jumptable+edx*4]

jumptable:
 dd branch1
 dd branch2

// ...

branch1:
 lea edx,[somestring]
 mov ah,09h
 int 21h

branch2:
 mov ax,4c00h
 int 21h
```

Of course for this example to make more sense initial value of `eax` should be dynamic.